# How call a custom function after input got validated in hook_form_alter?

Tags: 6, hooks, forms

I want to call custom functions for doing some profile filed updation on user registration. So i used to implement my custom functions in hook_form_alter. The code is here

```
<?php
function calculation_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
switch ($form_id) {
case 'user_register':
$form['#validate'][1] = 'do_database_updation';
break;
}
return $form;
}

function do_database_updation($form, &$form_state){
/* perform database updation here... */
}
```

It works fine, but the problem is when the validation fails, the database updation cannot be retrieved back. I want to call the custom function after validate the input values. How it to do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add your function in  the `[#submit]` key. For example :

```
if ( empty($form['#submit']) ) {
  $form['#submit'] = array();
}
array_push($form['#submit'], 'do_database_updation');
```

The submit handler is called after the validation.